# Decrypt Password protected pdf using itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

I need to decrypt password protected PDF using itextsharp.
Code i used for this is as follows

```
  string InputFile = @"C:\Users\Pro.pdf";
        string OutputFile = @"C:\Users\DecPro.pdf";
        string password = @"pswd123"; // Your Key Here
        try
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(InputFile, new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(password));
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, memoryStream);
                stamper.Close();
                reader.Close();
                File.WriteAllBytes(OutputFile, memoryStream.ToArray());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
        }
```

This code is perfectly working on my local machine but when i move this code to production environment we need to restart IIS. After restarting IIS it is working for first 5-10 mins then again its stop working.It does not able to decrypt PDF and saving PDF with password encryption. Can anyone help in this.

Answer (score 0):

For decrypt a PDF(without knowing the password) you have to use this code:

```
    PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
```

You can catch more information [here](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it5kb/faq/how-to-read-pdfs-created-with-an-unknown-random-owner-password)

Comment: *"For decrypt a PDF you have to use this code"* - No you don't _have to_ in general, only if you have "forgotten" your owner password

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, you are right. You can use that code when you don't know the password